# wildfly-service.exe crashes for Faulting module name: ntdll.dll

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, wildfly-10, windows-update

My wildfly 10.0.1 application server gives below error. I am running application to convert flat file to xml. This application is using multi threading, JABX and flatworm to convert flat file to xml and vice versa. Quartz scheduler running after every 4 min but when I executed first batch of files it processed successfully and for next batch of files it stop working and in server manager I got below error.

```
            Faulting application name: wildfly-service.exe, version: 1.0.15.0, time stamp: 0x51543b9d
            Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18438, time stamp: 0x57ae642e
            Exception code: 0xc0000374
            Fault offset: 0x00000000000f1b70
            Faulting process id: 0x840
            Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b6a91a72b8c6
            Faulting application path: D:\OTM_INTEGRATION\DJBOSS\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\service\amd64\wildfly-service.exe
            Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
            Report Id: 410fa34a-233f-11e7-810c-005056b336bb
            Faulting package full name: 
            Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I am experiencing this issue after installing below windows patches.

```
security update for microsoft windows(KB4015550)
update for microsoft windows(KB4014567)
update for microsoft windows(KB4014551)
```

In wildfly server log i got below debug log only, there is no error log there.

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.client.txn] (Periodic Recovery) Send recover request for transaction origin node identifier 1 to EJB receiver with node name <Node_name>
```

I am unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: Just an observation: your wildfly service should be stopped by you or by another process. The problem is with the shutdown process which was crashed given the race condition on ACDSR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Apache Commons Daemon Service Runner, which is used by Wildfly. See

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DAEMON-372 and

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9577

This shouldn't be a problem for your Web-App but you might create your own service-wrapper using a more up-to-date version of ACDSR if it bugs you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Comment: In general, I agree that including more details would be preferable. In this case I don't know what detail would have helped here. The root cause is a timing problem in the shutdown process of the ACDSR. A level of detail which is IMHO not helping. The solution is to create a new wrapper with the latest version. That's what I wrote.

Comment: That is why I only commented, and did not downvote or flag your answer ;-)